Cast can't get an instance of a Solidity contract
Given that Forge does not allow for direct interaction with deployed contracts and cast is not good for testing I am attempting to use both.
I have a verified contract that I want to get an instance from in cast to use in Forge. This function failed:
function getXToken(string calldata _xToken) public returns (XToken) {
    string[] memory inputs = new string[](4);
    inputs[0] = "cast";
    inputs[1] = "call";
    inputs[2] = _xToken;
    bytes memory result = vm.ffi(inputs);

    // Decode the result to get the contract address
    address contractAddress = abi.decode(result, (address));

    return XToken(contractAddress);
}

Then I decided to test the cast call alone to begin with but two of the following cast command fails.
cast call 0xe34Ac9E64fb1db3b3bb30988462014Cb525de040 --rpc-url https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Error: 
server returned an error response: error code -32000: execution reverted

cast call 0x0aa3E2929564BcD8bfD97d346D4bC3CC135f65Cd getBalance() --rpc-url https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Error: 
server returned an error response: error code -32000: execution reverted

But this transaction works and is visible on Sepolia.
cast send 0xe34Ac9E64fb1db3b3bb30988462014Cb525de040 mint(uint256) 1000000000000000000 --rpc-url https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --from 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693 --private-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Any idea how I can get two first call to work and get instance that I can later use?

To get the instance of the deployed contract, you can install and use the foundry-devops library, then you can simply call the get_most_recent_deployment() function as shown in the README.
For creating deployment and interaction scripts, you can refer to this part of the Foundry Full Course provided by Cyfrin Updraft. They've also showcased the usage of foundry-devops library.
And, for the cast call command, you need to put double quotes around your function name "getBalance()", like:
cast call 0xe34Ac9E64fb1db3b3bb30988462014Cb525de040 "getBalance()" --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com

Then, it would work fine:

